# Rotate pie chart which is a CALayer with touch events

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, core-animation, core-plot

Iam using core-plot for drawing pie charts. I am using this code in the touch drag event of the CPTPieChart.h.

```
   -(BOOL)pointingDeviceDraggedEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint{
         int x = self.anchorPoint.x;
         int y = self.anchorPoint.y;
         float dx = interactionPoint.x - x;
         float dy = interactionPoint.y - y;
         double a = atan2(dx,dy);
         self.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(a, 0, 0, 1);
         return YES;
    }
```

The piechart is rotating mildly but the top and bottom portion are clipping upon rotating.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any padding set on the graph?

Comment: I didn't set any padding. Should I need to set? Thanks.

Comment: You probably don't need the padding. I was just speculating about what could clip the plot. Is there any way you could post your graph setup code and/or a picture?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same clipping problem when rotating a CPTPieChart using `transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(a, 0, 0, 1)`. Not exactly sure what's causing it.

I worked around it by altering the `startAngle` property instead of the `transform` property.

See: http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/4372a7590c474c85