# How to rotate CPTGraphhostingview in core plot

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

please guide me how to rotate CPTGraphHostingView through single finger touch in both (clock and anti clock) direction

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotate pie chart which is a CALayer with touch events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788375/rotate-pie-chart-which-is-a-calayer-with-touch-events)

Answer (score 1):

//I have used this code for rotating pie chart for few seconds without user interaction.

```
-(void)ConstPieChart
{
     graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero]; 

     viewGraphHostingPie.hostedGraph=graph;

     CPPieChart *pieChart = [[CPPieChart alloc] init];
     pieChart.dataSource = self;
     pieChart.delegate = self;
     pieChart.pieRadius = 100.0;
     pieChart.identifier = @"PieChart1";
     pieChart.startAngle=0;
     //pieChart.startAngle = M_PI_4;
     pieChart.sliceDirection = CPPieDirectionCounterClockwise;



     NSMutableArray *ValueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     ValueArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:57.03],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:66.00],[NSNumber numberWithDouble:77.03],nil];
     self.pieData = ValueArray;




    CABasicAnimation *rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(360, 0, 0, 1);
    rotation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];
    rotation.duration = 15.0f;
    [pieChart addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"rotation"];
    [graph addPlot:pieChart];
     [pieChart release];
}
```